# Plotting error - error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running an R code (not mine) that is designed to read a table of contents and plot a graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- at <- read.table(file="User/alexanderzamani/Documents/results.txt", 
                        sep = "\t", header= TRUE)

#let's just look at a single mutation rate
r <- dat[which(dat$u==0.00010),]

#now let's plot it out
p <- ggplot(r, aes(x=S, y=k, group=pN))
p + geom_line(aes(color=pN), size=2, alpha=0.5) + geom_point() +
    xlab("Overlapping generations (proportion of offspring that survive)") + 
    ylab("substitution rate") + 
    scale_colour_gradient(name="Degree of\npopulationsize\nfluctuation")
```

after installing `ggplot2`, I ran the code and I it shows a blank quartz window and this error:

```
Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero
```

I have no prior experience with R, any help will be much appreciated.

-
*Edit*

Here is a link for the uploaded .txt file I am using -
http://txtup.co/NW6lU

Comment: It's really impossible to help you without a reproducible example.

Comment: thank you for the comment joran, I wish I could give an example. But all I know is the example would br a graph that plots the values 'S' over 'k' in groups of 'pN'. Right now I have only a blank output.

Comment: Ok. If you won't provide a reproducible example, I can't help. Good luck!

Comment: oh ok, what would be an example of a reproducible example, I'm new here sorry.

Comment: @AlexanderZamani Can you at least upload your data R file on dropbox.

Comment: sure, sorry this is not my program, the directory I use is User/alexanderzamani/Documents/results.txt sorry for the trouble I'll edit and upload the data. thanks

Comment: oh sorry the R file, that is the R file

Answer (score 6):

You are subsetting your `dat` to create `r` where column `u` equals 0.0001 when you do:

```
r <- dat[which(dat$u==0.0001),]
```

Is it possible you dont have any values that are at 0.0001....?

I did 0.1 and got:

[image]

Comment: Alexander you should select user1317221_G's response as an answer (will show up as green checkmark)